# I have hard time understanding Postgresql OVERLAP function when provided Interval

Tags: postgresql, datetime

On postgresql [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html) whilst reading for date and time operations I have hard time understanding the following example:

```
SELECT (DATE '2001-02-16', INTERVAL '100 days') OVERLAPS
       (DATE '2001-10-30', DATE '2002-10-30');
Result: false
```

I failed to understand the reason why it returns `false`, is it because an Interval is being passed as a parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand it, `(DATE '2001-02-16', INTERVAL '100 days')` is evaluated as `(DATE '2001-02-16', DATE '2001-02-16' + INTERVAL '100 days')`

Which in turn is the same as `(DATE '2001-02-16', DATE '2001-05-27')` and that obviously doesn't overlap with `(DATE '2001-10-30', DATE '2002-10-30')`